# Java Calculation Mistake

Tags: java, textfield

I am trying to create a program that calculates the futureValue that is in the following formula

```
             futureValue = investmentAmount × (1 + monthlyInterestRate)^years×12
```

It is a visual program and it calculates the futureValue.Variables: investmentAmount monthlyInterestRate and years are taken from textfields.Here my code is like this

```
public void Calculator(){
        double x = (Double.parseDouble(AnnualInterestRate.getText())/12) + 1;
        double y = Double.parseDouble(Years.getText()) * 12;
        double mult = Math.pow(x, y);

        double futureValue = Double.parseDouble(InvesmentAmount.getText()) * mult;
        lblNewLabel_3.setText("$" + String.format("%.2f",futureValue));

    }
```

for these values:
 InvesmentAmount     : 1000
 Years               : 2
 AnnualInterestRate  : 6.5
futureValue should be 1,138.43  but futureValue that is calculated by my program is 32491635,80

I can't see the mistake and It would be great if anybody could help.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: What happens if you divide by 12.0, and multiply by 12.0?

Comment: 6.5 percent is a scale of 0.065, not 6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user is supposed to be inputting the interest rate as a percentage, you need to divide it by 100 as part of your calculation. E.g.

```
double x = (Double.parseDouble(AnnualInterestRate.getText())/1200) + 1;
```

Output: $1138.43